# How to close already opened windows in WX python

Tags: python, wxpython

I am writing a program where main screen is having buttons like `Start`.

When I click on `Start` button it will open a new window.

New window will have buttons `Next`.

When we click on `Next` Button it will open again a window.

I have done all the coding and it is working as expected.

**Problem:**

I am not able to close the old windows when I start new window.

New window opens but old window remains there.

I am new to WX.

I am not getting how to do that

Below is the code :

```
import wx
import re

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    i = 1
    dict1 = {}
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "My Frame", size=(2000, 800))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        #panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION,  self.OnMove)
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Lets Play", pos=(80, 400))
        font = wx.Font(32, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)
        startButton=wx.Button(panel,label="Start",pos=(800, 400), size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.start, startButton)
        txt = open("questions.txt") 

        alist = []

        for line in txt:    
            if re.search("^\n", line): continue
            searchObj = re.search("([\d]+)\.\s*(.*)", line)
            if searchObj :
                i = searchObj.group(1)
                j = 1
                key = 'Q' + str(i)
                self.dict1[key] = searchObj.group(2)
            searchObj2 = re.search("^[a-z]\.\s*(.*)", line)
            if searchObj2 : 
                self.dict1[key,j] = (searchObj2.group(1))
                j = j + 1
            searchObj3 = re.search("Answer:\s*(\d)", line)
            if searchObj3 :
                self.dict1[key,"answer"] = searchObj3.group(1)
            searchObj4 = re.search("pic(\d)\.\s*(.*)", line)
            if searchObj4 :
                i = searchObj4.group(1)
                j = 1
                key = 'Q' + str(i)
                self.dict1[key] = searchObj4.group(2)
                self.dict1[key,'pic'] = "yes"
            searchObj5 = re.search("path:\s*(.*)", line)
            if searchObj5 : 
                self.dict1[key,'picPath'] = (searchObj5.group(1))


        self.dict1['totalQuestions'] = i
        txt.close()
        print self.dict1
    def start(self, event):
        # 
        dict1Index = self.i
        dict1 = self.dict1
        self.i = self.i + 1
        start = MyQuestionDialog(self, -1, "button", dict1Index, dict1)
        start.ShowModal()
        start.Destroy()
        # self.Close()

        # dict1Index = dict1Index + 1





class MyQuestionDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, dict1Index, dict1):
        self.dict1 = dict1
        self.dict1Index = dict1Index
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1000,1000))
        # panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        key = 'Q' + str(dict1Index)

        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, dict1[key], pos=(10, 12))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)
        # text.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        #self.posCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "", pos=(100, 10))
        dictPicKey = (key, "pic")
        # print "****dickey*************************",dictPicKey
        # print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",dict1
        if dictPicKey in dict1 :
            print "^^^^^^^^^######################################################"
            picPath = dict1[key, 'picPath']
            print "^^^^^^^^^",picPath
            start_image = wx.Image(picPath) 
            start_image.Rescale(500, 500) 
            image = wx.BitmapFromImage(start_image) 
            # mypic = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image, wx.DefaultPosition, style=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG) 
            mypic = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image, (10,100)) 
            self.option1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,1], (600,100), (160,-1)) 
            self.option2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,2], (600,150), (160,-1))
            self.option3 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,3], (600,200), (160,-1))         
            self.option4 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,4], (600,250), (160,-1))         
        else :
            self.option1 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,1], (20,100), (160,-1))
            self.option2 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,2], (20,150), (160,-1))
            self.option3 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,3], (20,200), (160,-1))
            self.option4 = wx.CheckBox(self, -1, dict1[key,4], (20,250), (160,-1))

        button=wx.Button(self,label="NEXT",pos=(800, 400), size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, frame.start, button)
        okButton=wx.Button(self,label="OK",pos=(600, 400), size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.checkAnswer, okButton)


        # nextButton=wx.Button(self,label="Next",pos=(1000, 400), size = (50,50))
        # self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.nextwindow, nextButton)
    def checkAnswer(self, event):
        self.getValue1 = self.option1.GetValue()
        self.getValue2 = self.option2.GetValue()
        self.getValue3 = self.option3.GetValue()
        self.getValue4 = self.option4.GetValue()
        key = 'Q' + str(self.dict1Index)
        qAnswer =  self.dict1[key,'answer']
        print "qAnswer is ########", qAnswer        
        ansKey = "self" + "." + "getValue" + qAnswer
        print "########anskey", eval(ansKey)
        ansKey = eval(ansKey)
        if ansKey == True :
            result = "correct"
            correctAnswer = ""
        else :
            result = "Incorrect"
            correctAnswer = self.dict1[key,int(qAnswer)]
        dia = MyDialog(self, -1, 'buttons', result, correctAnswer)
        dia.ShowModal()
        dia.Destroy()


class MyDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, answer, correctAnswer):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(350,300))
        text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, answer , pos=(100, 12))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)
        if answer == "correct" :
            text.SetForegroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        else :
            text.SetForegroundColour(wx.RED)
        str = "Correct Answer is : \n" + correctAnswer
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, str , pos=(100, 120))


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The general way to do this is to pass a reference to the old window object as an argument to the new one, then, in the new one, destroy the old one.

Comment: Can you just give me an example

Comment: If you destroy the original parent window, then the whole application well close. You should just hide the main window instead of closing it. However, it sounds like what you need is a wizard. wxPython has a wizard widget: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/adv.Wizard.html

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Can you point to an example having this wizard

Comment: How about this: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/27/wxpython-a-wizard-tutorial/